# Python pandas - Dropping grouped rows based on missing territory code

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, contains

In the df below, we have two "Mixes" as indicated by the Mix_Name and Mix_ID columns. And within each of these mixes are multiple tracks with unique Track_ID's that contain different territories (see Territories column).

```
Mix_Name    Mix_ID  Territories     Track_Title  Artist         Track_ID
Mix Vol 1   abc123  GB | US | MX    Cabala       Prok & Fitch   12345678
Mix Vol 1   abc123  US | CA         Autosave     Fedde          9101112
Mix Vol 1   abc123  US | CA         4 Life       Firebeatz      4151617
Mix Vol 1   abc123  IE | MX         4 Life       Firebeatz      18192021
Mix Vol 2   xyz456  CA              Warrior      My Nu Leng     22232425
Mix Vol 2   xyz456  FR | DE | NE    Warrior      My Nu Leng     27282930
Mix Vol 2   xyz456  US | CA         I'm Madonna  Madonna        31323334
Mix Vol 2   xyz456  CA | US | FR    Trouble      Gregor Salto   35363738
```

What I'm hoping to do here find out which tracks do not have the US territory, and if any of the tracks do not have the US territory, I will want to drop the entire mix from my dataframe. With the resulting dataframe looking like this because "Mix Vol 2" is missing the US territory in one of its tracks:

```
Mix_Name    Mix_ID  Territories     Track_Title  Artist         Track_ID
Mix Vol 1   abc123  GB | US | MX    Cabala       Prok & Fitch   12345678
Mix Vol 1   abc123  US | CA         Autosave     Fedde          9101112
Mix Vol 1   abc123  US | CA         4 Life       Firebeatz      4151617
Mix Vol 1   abc123  IE | MX         4 Life       Firebeatz      18192021
```

I know that I need to Groupby: 'Mix_ID', 'Track_Title', and 'Artist' but I'm unsure of how to search the territories column to see if it contains the "US" territory. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the dataframe here? That would be better, you can copy it from an exel or csv & paste it inside HTML portion of the "Code Snippet" (icon next to picture).

Comment: Edited! @mohanys

Comment: wouldn't Mix Vol 1 also be dropped because the last track doesn't contain US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby(['Mix_Name', 'Track', 'Artist']).filter(lambda x: (x['Territories'].str.contains('US').any()))
```

You do your groupby, then filter the groups to check if the territories column contains 'US'.

**EDIT**

```
notInUS = df.groupby(['Mix_Name','Track_Title','Artist']).filter(lambda x: ~x['Territories'].str.contains('US').any())['Mix_Name'].unique()
df[~df['Mix_Name'].isin(notInUS)]
```

We can look for the unique Mix_Name's that doesn't have a track in the US, then filter it out of our main df.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Ben Pap! This is great as it drops the groups that do not contain the US territory, but I hoping to drop the entire "Mix" if it contains any groups that do not have the US territory.

Comment: Change ```any()``` to ```all()``` and it will make sure they all have US.

Comment: Apologies, I'm afraid I'm not articulating my goal clearly. Referencing the edited DFs in my original post above, I have two unique IDs and within those two unique IDs, I am grouping rows by 'Mix_Name', 'Track', and 'Artist'. If any of these groups do not have "US" territory in the Territories column, then I would drop all mixes with that unique ID. The output df in my example should only contain one Mix_ID (xyz456) because each group has the US territory.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify if this is incorrect but, I think you are trying to:

identify any tracks that do not have US in 'Territories', then delete the entire Mix that this track belongs to.

If so, you can achieve this doing the following..

```
#get list of all Mix_Names that have at least 1 track without US in Territories
mixes_to_drop=df[~df['Territories'].str.contains('US')]['Mix_Name'].unique().tolist()
#filter out the mixes that have a 'Mix_Name' that is in the list of mixes to drop
df[~df['Mix_Name'].isin(mixes_to_drop)]
```

hope this helps or steers you in the right direction

Comment: looks like I got beat to the punch :D